# Is there a way to avoid returing keys with null values in Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a nullable attribute in a type:

```
type Person {
  job: String
}
```

And a query:

```
query Persons() {
  persons() {
    job
  }
}
```

Whevener I query the object, I always get the `job` key, either with a string or a null value.

```
{
  "job": null
}
```

But what I need is the `job` key to be present in the result only when the job is defined, otherwise I want it to be skipped altogether.

```
{}
```

I have tried returning `null`, `undefined` and skipping the key from the data, but Apollo always returns the key no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to delete field afterwards:

```
if (result.job === null) {
   delete result.job;
}
```

To achieve the same result with graphql you'll have to split `Person` into two types: `PersonWithJob` and `PersonWithoutJob`. Return a union from `persons` query and change your query to something like:

```
query Persons() {
  persons() {
    ... on PersonWithJob {
      job
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know it is easier to delete it afterwards, however I have generic code that is just supposed to pass the JSON as it is to an external system that requires the keys to be either absent or with data. I just don't want to have any special treatment in that code for that particular case.